# Append data to existing xml file without loading file into memory

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I want to add data to an existing xml file without having to load the existing file into momory.

I have a data model:

```
public class clsPerson
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public List<string> Likes;
}
```

and i have this code that adds two people to an xml file, closes the file and then i want to add another two people...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<clsPerson> p1 = new List<clsPerson>();
        p1.Add(new clsPerson { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Dow", Likes = new List<string> { "Apples", "Bananas" } });
        p1.Add(new clsPerson { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Dow", Likes = new List<string> { "Football", "Tennis" } });

        string file = @"D:\people.xml";

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p1.GetType());
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(file);
        x.Serialize(tw, p1);

        tw.Close();           


        List<clsPerson> p2 = new List<clsPerson>();

        p2.Add(new clsPerson { FirstName = "New", LastName = "Guy", Likes = new List<string> { "Reading", "Walking" } });
        p2.Add(new clsPerson { FirstName = "Another", LastName = "Girl", Likes = new List<string> { "Surfing", "Running" } });

        //... i want to add p2 to people.xml without having to load the entire file into memory again
}
```

I can add the two new entries by reloading the file, read all the nodes into a list and add the new entries, but this seems inefficient, especially if the xml had 1000's of entries in it.

Comment: Without loading it into memory, how are you supposed to determine where you're to insert the entries? Your question makes no sense to me. XML is a specific format of nodes (elements), and to write to it you have to load it to determine where to insert new nodes. To do it without loading it is turning it into a plain text file, and if that's what you need then don't use XML.

Comment: That's what i thought, although i was hoping for a better solution. So basically it can't be done?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. "To to it without loading is to turn it into a plain text file." If you don't want to use XML as XML, then don't use XML. :-)